# git format-patch creating invalid patches

Tags: git, patch

I'm pulling my hair already and would be glad about some help.

I'm exporting a git repository with files only by means of

```
git format-patch --root -o /tmp/foo
```

and trying to add the files with history to another repository, by means of

```
git am --directory=foo --reject /tmp/foo/*.patch
```

The directory a does not exist in the repository, hence there can't be any conflicts. The patches are the ONLY changes applied.

Still my patches fail.

The *services.sass.rej* file (from first failing patch 0067) contains this:

```
diff a/foo/services.sass b/foo/services.sass    (rejected hunks)
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
 @import compass/css3/background-size

header
-  background: white  url('/img/bg/angebot.jpg') no-repeat top center
+  background: white  url('../img/bg/angebot.jpg') no-repeat top center
   +background-size(100% auto)

   +fullView
```

When I check *services.sass*, it starts with the following:

```
@import globals
@import compass/css3/background-size
@import compass/css3/animation

header
  background: white  url('/img/bg/angebot.jpg') no-repeat top center
  +background-size(100% auto)

  +fullView
```

Therefore the patch was created completely wrong, missing a complete line (`@import compass/css3/animation`). How is that possible and how can I avoid that?

Comment: I just looked into the `git diff` for the commit producing the patch 0067, as well as into that version of the services.sass as into the following one. The animation-line is missing in all of them. So why is it still in the file when applying the patches?

Comment: For any normal (non-merge) commit, the patch from `git format-patch` is the same as the one you'd see with `git show` of the same commit ID, and is formed by diff-ing that commit against its parent.  Without more information that's all I can say here.